# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - Error on client computer

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows, sqlclient

I upgraded the environment for a client app which was developed on windows xp 32 bits to windows 10 with 64 bits.

The app is a client for a remote sql server, and it is based on wpf services. The server computer was also upgraded recently to Windows 7 with 64 bits system.

The app seems to work fine, but upon sending data to the server, I get the error:

> Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>        Inner exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**Stack Trace**

> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state).`

I tried installing different versions of dotnet framework, enabling tcp connections on the client computer, enabling connection on the firewall of the server and more.
What else can possibly cause this error?

Comment: Possibly not a firewall issue - it seems to be connecting initially. If your connection string is using the `Encrypt=True` setting you might be fighting TLS issues: Windows 7 does not support TLS 1.2 by default; Windows 10 now uses TLS 1.2 as its default protocol. Have a read through [Solving the TLS 1.0 Problem, 2nd Edition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem) to see if this is the case. See also [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3140245) for a possible fix.

Comment: btw, the important part of my second link isn't anything to do with WinHTTP (SQL connections don't use that), it's the SChannel configuration in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a TLS issue. Add this line before you send data to an external server to force TLS version that must be used for the connection

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```